# Running Access Macro in Powershell

Tags: powershell, ms-access, macros

I'm trying to run an Access 2010 macro in PowerShell (v4.0 Windows 8.1) with the below code:

```
$Access = New-Object -com Access.Application

$Access.OpenCurrentDatabase("SomePath", $False, "Password")
$Access.Run("SomeProc")
$Access.CloseCurrentDatabase()
$Access.Quit()

[System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($Access)
Remove-Variable Access
```

I get an error on the line `$Access.Run("SomeProc")` that there's not enough parameters specified:

> Exception calling "Run" with "1" argument(s): "Invalid number of parameters. (Exception 
>   from HRESULT: 0x8002000E (DISP_E_BADPARAMCOUNT))"

The procedure `SomeProc` does not require any parameters.

I've read the [msdn article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193559(v=office.14).aspx) on the run method and only one parameter is required.

I've also tried [this workaround](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/654e81a7-e998-4575-9261-ad4d2507117a/how-to-invoke-ms-access-vba-function?forum=winserverpowershell) which also failed to work for an unrelated reason.

Does anyone know what the cause of the error could be and how to get the method working?

Comment: Does your `SomeProc` require parameters itself?

Comment: @Vesper Sorry should have clarified, no parameters are expected by the procedure.

Comment: Do you run into the same problem with a minimal procedure ... `$Access.Run("SayHello")` where *SayHello* is a public sub which includes only `MsgBox "Hello Word!"`

Comment: @HansUp Thanks, just tried creating a basic procedure and no luck, receiving the same error.

Comment: Nuts!  I just tested the VBScript equivalent of your PowerShell code and can't see why there should be a problem.  Sorry, I'm not proficient with PowerShell.  Can you show us the code from your *SomeProc* procedure?  If it's a monster, please show us a minimal version which triggers the same error.

Comment: @HansUp thanks - I'm actually migrating from vbscript to powershell and the procedure and vbscript equivalent defo works! That's the annoying part so assume it's a powershell issue

Comment: Will PowerShell let you call the procedure without including parentheses like this: `$Access.Run "SomeProc"`  If so, does that change anything?

Comment: @HansUp No it wont. Shall we move this to chat?

Comment: I'm out of ideas, so chat would not be useful.  I suspect you need help from someone who is PowerShell-proficient.  Sorry I couldn't help.

Comment: @HansUp No worries, thanks for your time :)

Comment: @Gareth How About `$Access.Run("SomeProc",$null)` ?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Thanks, it now throws the error `Argument: '2' should be a System.Management.Automation.PSReference. Use [ref].
At line:4 char:1`

Comment: `which also failed to work for an unrelated reason.` what was the reason that solution doesn't work?

Comment: @Newd related to vbscript issues on the new machine which cannot (due to administrative reasons) be overcome. The solution manually will work ie the script and access procedures fire fine. Cheers

Comment: I am unable to recreate your issue under the PowerShell ISE on 32-bit Windows 8.1 with Office 2010. I pasted your code into a new ISE code window, adjusted the file path and `Sub` name, and hit [F5] to run the script. It ran my VBA `Sub` in the Access database without complaint.

Comment: Thanks @GordThompson the only difference is that I'm in a 64 bit environment. The procedure works, and the vbscript works fine. Must be a 64 bit issue?!

Comment: No problems for me with either "PowerShell ISE" (64-bit) or "PowerShell ISE (x86)" (32-bit) and 64-bit Office 2010 under Windows 7. It's starting to sound like your issue has to do with the configuration of your particular machine. (Perhaps the same reason why VBScript and the other workaround don't work.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a driver issue where the OLEDB libraries aren't loading correctly.

I was able to reproduce your error exactly, and I was able to work around it by opening Powershell from your SysWow directory instead of System32.

Try opening this version of Powershell (you'll have to run set-executionpolicy again), and see if it'll execute your script.

**%SystemRoot%\syswow64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe**

Helpful link: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4500877f-0031-426e-869d-bda33d9fe254/microsoftaceoledb120-provider-cannot-be-found-it-may-not-be-properly-installed?forum=adodotnetdataproviders

Answer (score 2):

The C# signature is something like this:

```
public object Run(string Procedure, ref object Arg1, ... ref object Arg30) ...
```

It means that COM the Arg optional arguments are not optional in .NET because they are explicitly marked as [ref]. You need to provide all 32 args even if you don't use them.

---

Assuming you have the following VBA code:

```
Public Sub Greeting(ByVal strName As String)
 MsgBox ("Hello, " & strName & "!"), vbInformation, "Greetings"
End Sub
```

You can either use call it like this:

```
$Access = New-Object -com Access.Application
$Access.OpenCurrentDatabase("Database1.accdb")
$runArgs = @([System.Reflection.Missing]::Value) * 31
$runArgs[0] = "Greeting" #Method Name
$runArgs[1] = "Jeno" #First Arg
$Access.GetType().GetMethod("Run").Invoke($Access, $runArgs)
```

In your case it will be:

```
$runArgs = @([System.Reflection.Missing]::Value) * 31
$runArgs[0] = "SomeProc" 
$Access.GetType().GetMethod("Run").Invoke($Access, $runArgs)
```

I would probably try to add a helper to the access object:

```
Add-Member -InputObject $Access -MemberType ScriptMethod -Name "Run2" -Value {
    $runArgs = @([System.Reflection.Missing]::Value) * 31
    for($i = 0; $i -lt $args.Length; $i++){ $runArgs[$i] = $args[$i] }
    $this.GetType().GetMethod("Run").Invoke($this, $runArgs)
}
```

Then you can use Run2 as you would expect:

```
$Access.Run2("Greeting", "Jeno")
$Access.Run2("SomeProc")
```

Comment: There is definitely an overload to the `.Run()` method that takes only one argument: the name of the procedure. As I mention in my comments to the question, I had no problems with the asker's sample code when I tried it on a couple of my machines.

Comment: I created a C# project and referenced the dll. I see only one method. I don't see overloaded ones. The sample didn't work for me until I passed in all arguments. What is the full name of the assembly you are using? Maybe the issue is related to versions.

Comment: $Access.GetType().GetMethod("Run").Count # will give me 1

Comment: $Access.GetType().GetMethod("Run").GetParameters() | Format-Table
# gives me a a list of 31 mandatory arguments

Comment: Sorry for the imprecise wording. On my machine it's not an overload, it's just that the 30 argument parameters for the `.Run()` method are *optional* parameters whose default values are all `Type.Missing` ([screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/td07n.png)). All I did was add the "Microsoft Access 14.0 Object Library [reference](http://i.stack.imgur.com/tUZQD.png) to my C# 2010 project and then use `accApp.Run("logger");` in C# to run the `Sub logger()` VBA code in my Access 2010 database. (I was also able to do the same thing from PowerShell ISE as mentioned in my comments to the question.)

Comment: I don't think you use the same dll. Powershell seems to use Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access. It is the name I get when I run: (New-Object -com Access.Application).GetType().Assembly.GetName().Name

Comment: When I do `Console.WriteLine(accApp.GetType().Assembly.GetName().Name);` in my C# code I get "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access". That looks like the same assembly to me.

Comment: I'll chime in here and state that only the first argument to the `Run()` method is required, as stated in the [TechNet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193559.aspx) page regarding it.

Comment: I think it is related to the dll version. For me it only works in Poweshell if I provide all arguments. Otherwise I get the same error Gareth got. I am running the 64 bit powershell version so I am not sure how the accepted answer solves this issue. It didn't work for me.

Comment: I don't think that not being to reproduce the original issue on your machine invalidates my answer. I can delete it but it does work. The TechNet page you shared shows the VBA example. We knew it works okay in VBA.